# public variable in App class can't get referenced in other class xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this as my `App.xaml.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace MyShop
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public string productsJSON = {{very large string}};
        public List<Product> jsonDataCollection = new List<Product>();
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            jsonDataCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(productsJSON);
            foreach (Product p in jsonDataCollection)
            { 
                Application.Current.Properties[p.Id] = 0;
            }

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
        }
 ...
```

In my `ProductsPage.xaml.cs`, I want to reference the public variable `productsJSON` so I call it as `App.productsJSON` and assigned to a string variable `productsJSON`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace MyShop
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductsPage(string title)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = title;

            string productsJSON = App.productsJSON;

            displayProducts(productsJSON);
        }
    ...
```

For that, I get the error:
`CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'App.productsJSON'`

I'm confused because from the solutions online when referencing a property from another class, you just call the class then dot, and then the property name. I don't quite get the `object reference` error and it didn't work when I casted it to string like `<string>App.productsJSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a reference to the **instance** of the `App` class in order to access a non-static field or property

```
var json = ((App)Application.Current).productsJSON;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I also found out about `Application.Current.Properties`.
When I set `Application.Current.Properties["productsJSON"] = {{ very large string}}` in the App class, I can reference it in ProductsPage class by just calling `Application.Current.Properties["productsJSON"]`. In my situation where my goal is just to retrieve the string, is there a huge difference between the two approaches?